# index jumps to the top of the page

Tags: titlesec, indexing

[image]

My index jumps to the top of the page. I am currently using the following code.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,11.5pt,twoside, openleft]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec} 
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\boldindex}[1]{\textcolor{DarkPurple}{\textbf{#1}}\nouppercase{\index{#1}}}
\makeindex[intoc] 

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{}{}{-2pt}{\hskip5.5cm\centering\Huge \bfseries \mbox}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-120pt}{27pt}

\definecolor{DarkPurple}{RGB}{63, 22, 59}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand\indexname{Begrippen Index}

\boldindex{Test}\\
\boldindex{tEst}\\
\boldindex{teSt}\\
\boldindex{tesT}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Does anybody know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Please, make a compilable example that shows the issue.

Comment: @egreg I've updated the code

Comment: ! Undefined control sequence.
\boldindex ...rkPurple}{\textbf {#1}}\nouppercase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved adding  `\titleformat{name=\chapter, numberless}[block]{}{}{0pt}{\filright \Huge \bfseries}[\vskip4.5pt]`  to the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your posted code produces nurelated errors but in the `book` class the index heading is essentially set as

```
                \twocolumn[\@makeschapterhead{\indexname}]
```

so this forces a new page does a `\chapter*` style heading and then sets the index in two column. This is by design but you can define the `theindex` command in whatever way you want.  Also `imakeindex` package forces a new page unless you use `[nonewpage]`

[image]

```
%\documentclass[a4paper,11.5pt,twoside, openleft]{book}
% there is no 11.5 or openleft option
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside, openany]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec} 
\usepackage[nonewpage]{imakeidx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\boldindex}[1]{\textcolor{DarkPurple}{\textbf{#1}}{\index{#1}}}
\makeindex[intoc] 

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{}{}{-2pt}{\hskip5.5cm\centering\Huge \bfseries \mbox}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-120pt}{27pt}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{theindex}
{\section*{index}%
\let\item\@idxitem}
{}
\makeatother

\definecolor{DarkPurple}{RGB}{63, 22, 59}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand\indexname{Begrippen Index}

\boldindex{Test}\\
\boldindex{tEst}\\
\boldindex{teSt}\\
\boldindex{tesT}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: it works, but the \renewcommand\indexname{Begrippen Index} does not work.

Comment: oh change `\section*{index}%`to `\section*{\indexname}%` @superHenry

Comment: Is there a way to have a two row index? Just like in my first picture?

Comment: @superHenry switching to two column implies a page break and you asked for the page break to be removed.  (but you could load multicol and have \begin{multicols}{2}  and \end{multicols} in thet environment definition